# Is there a (better) way to find all references to a property setter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio's "Find All References" function works nicely for finding references to a property, and as it happens the "Call Hierarchy" does this too -  it's even better in fact, as it sorts them by calling method.

My problem however is that neither of these methods discriminate between the setter and getter, and so I'm reduced to using find-in-files for "PropertyName =".

That seems like a step backwards (and would obviously not find code using "PropertyName += value" or similar), so I was wondering if I'd missed a simple way of persuading the "Call Hierarchy" function of Visual Studio to work on a property setter or getter specifically?

Comment: Probably not without writing your own setter / getter methods in the traditional way, like `getNumber()`, `setNumber()`.

Comment: Sorry for the Product Plug, but Resharper can do that - plus a bazillion other things. It's worth at least taking a look at if you haven't.

Comment: I'm aware of how amazing Resharper is, but unfortunately it's not plausible for me at the moment. Also, Mellamokb, saying "Not really, no, not without [foo]" is a perfectly good answer - if you write it up and nobody else has any interesting workarounds, I'll probably go with it.

Comment: I wonder if this has changed in Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible in Visual Studio 2019 to sort and filter by "Kind" using the "Find All References" function.
The feature was requested on Microsoft's [developercommunity forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/386565/find-all-reference-distinguish-setter.html)

The "references" window with the "Kind" column is displayed to the very right, highlighted by a orange box.
[image: references window with the "Kind" column]

Comment: Thanks for letting me (and everyone else) know that this has changed now. Looks good!

Comment: *** ALSO in VS 2019: Rt-click on "set" keyword e.g. w/i `bool MyProp { get; set; }` now lists ONLY the setters :)

Comment: btw today i found out this technique can also be used to filter to specific overriden member by using Definition column that is not shown by default. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64277632/981396

Answer (score 27):

Resharper can do that for you.

Without R#, one way would be to temporarly set the setter to private and recompile.  That will give an error everywhere you're trying to set.  Not pretty, but faster than any other method I can think of.

Comment: It doesn't work in base Visual Studio unfortunately, it tells me it's not a method name, and the only thing that seems to allow call heirarchy on a property is the property name itself.

Comment: @Ben, he's telling you to change the setter to `private set`, then rebuild and look for compile errors. That will work without any refactoring tools at all.

Comment: @JSBangs:  My original answer suggested that VS without Resharper could do this, but it can't.  So I edited my answer to include the option of changing the setter to private and recompiling.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I hadn't thought about setting it to private, actually... That should do for a quick fix, thanks. It doesn't need to be pretty if it works, at least in this case :)

Comment: +1; this is what I do, though still hope a cleaner solution will present itself in the future.

Comment: Now do it for c++ :)

Comment: Better than setting to private is to remove the setter entirely, so that accesses within the same class can be found (if that's desired). Also, set-only properties can be written (but prepare to be shot if doing it in committed code!) for finding all accesses to the getter via compile errors. Very annoying that Visual Studio refuses to share with me information that it certainly knows (which accesses are calling getter and which calling setter!).

Answer (score 0):

This functionality now exists in Visual Studio 2022. You can click on the set keyword and click Shift+F12 (or right click and select Find all references) and it would display "Write" kind of references.

Note that, for a List or similar object, Add or Remove calls are considered as a Read reference (although you are changing the content of the list) because you are calling a method of the List class.