# Finding all references of a common method name in Visual Studio 2010 for a C# solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, if I right-click a method and choose "Find All References", it simply displays use of all methods with the same name rather than use of the method of that actual class.

The solution is C# rather than C++, so I can't find a way to [switch to accuracy mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/11/17/improvements-to-find-all-references-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx). Also, I cannot simply [make the method private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981149/is-there-a-better-way-to-find-all-references-to-a-property-setter#5981271) or comment it out to generate errors as the method is an `override`:

```
public override string ToString() { ... }
```

Is there any way of finding all uses of a particular class method in a solution without trawling through every single name match (in this case every instance of `ToString()` in the solution)?

Comment: It is not displaying all methods with the same name. What it does is the following: It knows that `ToString` is overridden in your class and it displays all usages of the initial declaration `object.ToString`.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Shift+F (Find in Files)?  You can limit the scope to only files in your solution or project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using Daniel Hilgarth's comment I found a solution: temporarily remove `override` from the declaration and it will show only references to that classes `ToString()` rather than the `ToString()` for all `object`'s.

Comment: Genius in its simplicity, love it.  :-)