# Find All References to an overriden method in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have an interface `ISomething` which defines `GetSomething()`.

I have a bunch of classes `Something1`, `Something2`,... all implement `ISomething` and therefore `GetSomething()`.

When I right-click on `Something1.GetSomething()` and click `Find All References`, VisualStudio shows all references to `ISomething.GetSomething()` instead of the actual derived class.

I'm wondering if there is a way to navigate to `Something1.GetSomething()` without scrolling down all the implementations of `GetSomething()`

Comment: So that's why if Visual Studio will crash if you try to find all references to `MyClass.ToString()`. It searches instead for `object.ToString()` and finds more results than it can handle.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Right next to Find All References is View Call Hierarchy.  It breaks up references to the selected member into 3 groups: Calls To, Calls From, and Implements.  You're probably looking for the last one.

[image: Call Hierarchy]

Answer (score 1):

Found another way today that is using standard Find References results window. Just use Find All References as usual and then in results window right click anywhere on table header and check Show Columns -> Definition. And then click on Definition column and set filter just to overriden member you are interested in.

[image]